# Why not all Events in WPF Controls

Tags: wpf, events

I want to use the TreeView.AfterCollapse Event in WPF .
Is there a Way to use it??
and why are not all Events supported in WPF?
Thank you

Comment: The System.Windows.Forms.TreeView is a different control than the System.Windows.Controls.TreeView. In WinForms you will be using one, and in WPF you will be using the other. Not sure why this event hasn't been migrated by Microsoft however.

Comment: yeah ok i know that but i was wondering if somehow i could add an event from system.windows.forms.treeview to my System.Windows.Controls.TreeView.

Comment: You can't. Like fatty said they're two totally different controls. It's the same reason why not all WinForms events are supported in WPF, because **WinForms is just not WPF**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TreeViewItem` has a [`Collapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.collapsed.aspx) event which is equivalent to the `AfterCollapsed` event in Windows Forms. This event is initially raised by the `TreeViewItem`, not the `TreeView`, but since it's a bubbling event, it is also raised on the `TreeView` afterwards, so you can handle it at this level if you need to. You can use the `OriginalSource` property to get the `TreeViewItem` that raised the event:

**XAML**

```
<TreeView TreeViewItem.Collapsed="TreeViewItem_Collapsed" ...>
```

**Code-behind**

```
private void TreeViewItem_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i knew how to use TreeViewItem Collapsed . But my problem was after my treevieitem collapses my multibinding generates other treeviewitems and i wanted to access them. So i thought if  i had an event that fires after the treeViewItem is collapsed and REFILLED i would see my new newly created TreeViewItem .   I should probably post another more specific question

Comment: @Mohamed, if your TreeViewItems are generated through binding, have a look at the |ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) property

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the TreeViewItem object to add this functionality.

Below is an example I've used.  It comes from Wei Zhou whose MSDN posts saved me a couple of times:

```
public class MyTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CollapsingEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Collapsing",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(MyTreeViewItem));
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ExpandingEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Expanding",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(MyTreeViewItem));
    public event RoutedEventHandler Collapsing
    {
        add { AddHandler(CollapsingEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CollapsingEvent, value); }
    } 
    public event RoutedEventHandler Expanding
    {
        add { AddHandler(ExpandingEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ExpandingEvent, value); }
    }
    protected override void OnExpanded(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnExpanding(new RoutedEventArgs(ExpandingEvent, this));
        base.OnExpanded(e);
    }
    protected override void OnCollapsed(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCollapsing(new RoutedEventArgs(CollapsingEvent, this));
        base.OnCollapsed(e);
    }
    protected virtual void OnCollapsing(RoutedEventArgs e) { RaiseEvent(e); }
    protected virtual void OnExpanding(RoutedEventArgs e) { RaiseEvent(e); }
}
```

Comment: This is useless... when your Collapsing event will be raised, the TreeViewItem will already be collapsed. OnCollapsed doesn't collapse the TreeViewItem, it only raises the event...

Comment: @Josh Thank you though but i wanted the AfterExpanding(And Refilling) Event .